# How to fix my url

Tags: php, html

I've got a some pages and when I press the text from one page I want to send аn id to the other page . I did it and everything works

```
<td  align="left" colspan="100%"  ><a class="Zaglavie" href="novina.php?id=<?= $rowB['id'] ?>&cat_id=<?=$rowB['cat_id']?>" >  <?php echo $rowB['name'];  ?></a></td>
```

and I have that url:

```
http://localhost/Tnews/novina.php?id=114&cat_id=2
```

But when I try to do it again something goes wrong with that code

```
<a class="titleMini" href="categories.php?id=<?= $row['path'] ?>&cat_id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row["name"];
```

and I get that url :

> `http://localhost/Tnews/categories.php?id=%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20path%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:\xampp\htdocs\Tnews\Main.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E164%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E&cat_id=4`

Comment: local path ? There is a PHP error in your URL . `Undefined index: path in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Tnews\Main.php</b> on line <b>164</b><br />&cat_id=4`

Comment: Im going to guess that for the second link you just missed the end of the code right? As its not closed.

Comment: The notice is quite self explanatory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means You don't ve     'path' index in     $row array..

Answer (score -1):

please check `$row['path']`  is not defined,

Comment: actually it's `path`, not `id`